# Obtaining Scheduler Information in a Many-Process Linux System

Tags: python, c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I have been trying to study multi-core implementation and using Raspberry Pi to achieve some tasks. Those tasks are independent applications in Linux and are run parallel by the Linux' process kernel. Those are some of the processes I run by shell:

```
sudo python App1.py &
sudo python App2.py &
sudo python App3.py &
sudo ./CPPApplication &
sudo ./XtightVNC &
sudo service start apache2 &
sudo ./mjpg-streamer
```

Imagine having a system like this, where not only Python and C applications are involved, but also some system services and out-of-reach executables.

I want to see how Linux' scheduler handle these independent tasks. For example if I use 'taskset' in order to place every one of those on core 3, I want to see the start time, release time, end time and so on as well as the scheduling states of those processes. And then maybe log all the data in a format like (can be Python or C-based logger):

```
App1 -> start  at system timer:0
App2 -> start at system timer :0.32
```

and so on..

Is something like this possible? If so, I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if I need to provide something else.

Comment: You can use trace events http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/trace/events.txt

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But this requires tracepoints to be placed in C applications. As I do not have that much access over some processes, and I have a lot of Python applications; I'm trying to find a way to learn these things from an outer scope. Is it possible to trace how these processes are scheduled and their schedule-related timing information?